# Using of @ViewChildren in a servive.ts results in undefined

Tags: angular

If I use ViewChildren to find some certain elements, I get an undefined error because I am using it in a service. How it is possible to load the children in a service if the service is used in multiple HTML Files?

```js
export class FormControlService {

  @ViewChildren('focusable', {read: ElementRef}) focusableField: QueryList<ElementRef>;

........
........
........

 setFocusDurchLink(event) {

    this.dialogSektionen.forEach(element => {

        if (element.sektionTitel === event.target.innerHTML) {

          for (let i = 0; i < this.focusableField.length; i++) { // <-- Here undefined

...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getter and setter to manage that. It makes the code much easier to read.

[Here is a working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vj6djy)

```js
export class AppComponent {

  get divs() { return this.service.divs; }

  @ViewChildren('divs') 
  set divs(value: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>>) {
    // For lifecycle error, use timeout
    setTimeout(() => this.service.divs = value);
  }

  constructor(
    public service: MyService
  ) { }
}
```

```js
export class MyService {

  public divs: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>>;

  constructor() { }

}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let i of [1, 2, 3]" #divs>div n° {{ i }}</div>

<br><br>

<div>
  Number of divs in the service : {{ service?.divs?.length }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `@ViewChildren` in service as it has no template. But you can pass it from the component while calling the method of the service:

```
export class MyComponent{

   @ViewChildren('focusable', {read: ElementRef}) focusableField: QueryList<ElementRef>;

   constructor(private fcs: FormControlService){}

   doSomething = (event) => { 
     this.fcs.setFocusDurchLink(event, this.focusableField);
   }
}
```

And of course you need to modify service:

```
export class FormControlService {


 setFocusDurchLink(event, focusableField: QueryList<ElementRef>) {

    this.dialogSektionen.forEach(element => {

        if (element.sektionTitel === event.target.innerHTML) {

          for (let i = 0; i < focusableField.length; i++) { 

...

}
```

You can read more on `@ViewChildren`, `@ViewChild`, `@ContentChildren` and `@ContentChild` here:

https://medium.com/@tkssharma/understanding-viewchildren-viewchild-contentchildren-and-contentchild-b16c9e0358e

Comment: Thank you, but I should have mention that there is another component between the focusable fields and the service and there is the call for the function. With the answer from Maryannah it works fine for me